# Modifying InstantSearch Android examples causes an exception

Tags: android, algolia

I have tried to run the e-commerce demo from [this link](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples), which I modified by setting the search bar in the custom action bar and calling hit_item UI in the fragment. But I get this error:

```
09-21 19:04:04.393 11716-11716/e_green_book.com.e_green_book E/EventBus: Could not dispatch event: class com.algolia.instantsearch.events.SearchEvent to subscribing class class com.algolia.instantsearch.helpers.SearchProgressController
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.algolia.instantsearch.utils.SearchViewFacade.<init>(SearchViewFacade.java:40)
    at com.algolia.instantsearch.helpers.InstantSearch.updateProgressBar(InstantSearch.java:420)
    at com.algolia.instantsearch.helpers.InstantSearch.access$100(InstantSearch.java:47)
    at com.algolia.instantsearch.helpers.InstantSearch$1.onStart(InstantSearch.java:191)
    at com.algolia.instantsearch.helpers.SearchProgressController.onSearch(SearchProgressController.java:66)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:485)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:416)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:397)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:370)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:251)
    at com.algolia.instantsearch.helpers.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:172)
    at com.e_commerce.e_green_book.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:200)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6736)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2744)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
```

Is this error expected? How can I use InstantSearch Android?

Comment: Hi Deep Doshi, I cannot reproduce your situation when downloading the code and running it directly. Did you modify the application's code? On what platform are you running it?

Comment: I have set search bar in the custom action bar and calling hit_item UI in the fragment .

Comment: Could you share this code in your question?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use InstantSearch Android out of the box.

If the issue you're facing happens **only when you modify the code**, you should **post your changes** in your question to let us understand your specific situation.

Using only the stack trace you shared, it seems the **`menu`** reference you are passing in `registerSearchView(activity, menu, id)` does not contain a View using the given **`id`**:

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(id).getActionView();
```

This throwing a `NullPointerException`, you should check the `menu` and `id` parameters of the `registerSearchView` call to ensure the Menu indeed contains a SearchView with this `id`.

Comment: Glad to hear! If it was thanks to my answer, can you accept it? Else could you let us know how you solved the error?